# Reinstalling drupal module

Tags: drupal-modules, uninstallation

I had trouble with the Open layer module in Drupal I therefore decided to reinstall it. I think I have done it properly. First I disabled the modules and then I unistalled them. When I should install the module again I could not do it because I get a massage that the module already was installed. When I looked in the module list I discovered that the modules still was there but disabled. It was not in the uninstall list and the directories was erased and the tables was not there.
I do not what to do to be able to install the module again.
Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!
I had wrong. The directories in the module map was not erased. Did that and it all works fine.